# if you use the shutdown.exe on a windows 8 will it wait for updates to be installed

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

Question basically in the title.

I am leaving a laptop with the inlaws who arent that good with technology.

I have created a shutdown.exe file on the task bar for them to close windows but am worried this wont wait for updates to be installed. Will this be fine.

Comment: It will depend on what you have written in your shutdown.exe,That is how you are doing shut down operation, Forcefully or Normal. But I think only power-off will stop the update operation .

Answer (score 1):

You created your own or referenced existing shutdown.exe?

My favorite way to reboot, is running SHUTDOWN -R -T 0 -F

I only issue this command after verbally speaking to users and asking if they've saved their work, though. The -F is essentially "fu*k your open documents." Maybe it's a bad habit from working in the retail POS industry for a while.

It does install updates, but does not provide much of a friendly window of opportunity to shut down open applications. Depending on the OS it gives a short window to abort and save work.. But its damn aggressive.

Comment: Thanks @beeks. This is the same as what I have done. I have given it a timer of 10seconds before the shut down so that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can live Automatic download and install Updates and the process of update will go during the work time. The updates that need restart will auto schedule for installation during shutdown or restart.

Better not force the shutdown use only `shutdown -s -t 0`